# File Already Exists When Moving File

Tags: c#, file, winapi, directory

In Windows Explorer you can have this structure:

- Main Directory

  - New Directory`(a directory)`
  - New Directory`(a file without an extension)`

My structure is:

- Main Directory

  - New Directory`(a directory)`
  - Some File.txt

What I'm trying to do is rename "Some File.txt" to "New Directory", like you can in Explorer. I'm using `File.Move("/Main Directory/Some File.txt", "/Main Directory/New Directory");`

However, I keep getting an exception saying

> Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

I assume it's not liking the fact that there's a directory named "New Directory". But given the fact that a directory and file with the same name may coexist, I don't see why the `Move` API fusses about this.

Is there some way to tell it to ignore directories with the same name when copying files, and vice versa?

**EDIT**: I recently reinstalled Windows and forgot to turn file extensions back on, so my rename in Explorer wasn't modifying the extension like I'm used to it doing. With extensions on, I can't perform the rename. So behavior is actually as expected. I'll leave this here in case someone does the same thing in the future.

Comment: "But given the fact that a directory and file with the same name may coexist..." is simply wrong: They cannot co-exist with the same name, because a directory is like a file, but with some differences.

Comment: Have you actually tried to rename a file to have the same name as a folder? I think you'll find that you actually ***can't*** do it.

Comment: @zx485 I just realized that I had a total mind blank and had file extensions turned off, so my rename in Explorer wasn't modifying the extension. With extensions on I can't perform the rename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... given the fact that a directory and file with the same name may coexist ...

That statement is incorrect. Each object in a container must have a distinct name. Presumably your shell is configured to hide extensions of registered file types which is leading you to make this erroneous statement.

The error message reported is accurate and cannot be avoided without renaming one of the files.

Comment: Technically, is possible in Windows explorer, that two items have two same display names.

Comment: @user2120666 I'm referring to the file system, which is what matters with `File.Move`.

Comment: I am only pointing that in Windows Explorer (as OP explicitly wrote) is this possible. But filesystem is another beast.

Comment: @user2120666 No, the statement that *"given the fact that a directory and file with the same name may coexist"* is simply false. The terms directory and file and the mention of `File.Move` imply we are referring to the file system, and not the more broad shell namespace in which the file system is contained.

Comment: @user2120666 "*Technically, is possible in Windows explorer, that two items have the same **display names**.*" Only if file extensions are being hidden. But that is just for **display** purpose, they do not have the same name on the file system or within the Shell namespace.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: No, you are not right. "Only if file extensions are being hidden" - this is false.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Why are you so aggressive? I am only points that Windows Explorer may contains two items with same display name. Period.

Comment: @user I don't see any aggression. I don't see the relevance of your comments though.

Comment: @user I explained that in the answer I think. Did I get anything wrong?

Comment: No, your answer is right (maybe replacing word 'container' with 'filesystem' is better). But you have problem with my comment.

Comment: @user No, container is the correct term. Folder or directory are examples of containers. I don't see the relevance of your comment.

Comment: So again and again: read again first sentence of question: In Windows EXplorer.... Do you see this words?

Comment: @user Yes. But the body of the question concerns the asker's C# program with operates on the file system. The display aspect with Explorer is also covered in my answer.